# SSH unexpectedly closing network connections

Tags: ssh, openssh

So I've been using this server daily for a few years now. Never had a single problem. Wake up this morning and I'm having trouble connecting to my box via SSH.

After about 10 attempts I restarted OpenSSH (5.3) and then I was able to connect (I had an existing connection via another client sitting idle from last night). Disconnected and reconnected a few times and all seemed well, but then I couldn't connect again. Tried stopping and starting OpenSSH again and it didn't help right away, but then I could connect again 20 minutes later. So it seems kind of random ...

I don't see any updates or anything unusually overnight -does anyone know what might cause this?

The only thing I did notice was that my disk cache spiked by about 2 gigs overnight as well. Related? I don't know...

Here's a few lines from my FTP client - it authenticates fine, but then the server just drops the connection...

```
! 2014-05-03 08:22:48.053 Using username "********".
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.159 Prompt (7, SSH password, , &Password: )
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.159 Using stored password.
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.195 Sent password
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.265 Access granted
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.265 Opening session as main channel
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.340 Opened main channel
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.506 Primary command failed; attempting fallback
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.561 Server unexpectedly closed network connection
. 2014-05-03 08:22:48.561 Using non-standard protocol or port, tunnel or proxy, will not knock FTP port.
* 2014-05-03 08:22:48.600 (EFatal) Server unexpectedly closed network connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, sudden closing of an ssh session post-access granted is one of a couple of things (my step 4, below, is what my gut tells me though).  However, I recommend starting a troubleshooting sequence based on the OSI model to get to the bottom of it.  Start with the physical (connections) and work your way up.

1. Check connections.  Sudden, un-provoked, changes in a network are all too often mechanical in nature to be overlooked.
2. Network.  I think this is more of a last ditch effort.  Any network hardware inbetween your host and server could be having issues.  Check your health statistics of these components if you can.  For a shortcut, just reboot them.
3. Firewall.  Not knowing your setup, this might be something to check.
4. Memory issue.  Either your client or your server may have an issue here.  This, to me, is the most likely culprit.  Usually, what happens is your system cant support the decryption and/or buffering required so the session is aborted.  Definitely clear your cache to get a fresh start.
5. Any software updates.  Did you recently receive a software update?  Perhaps permissions/configuration settings have changed in the process.

I've been thinking about this one since you posted it, but havent had a chance to write back.  Please let me know how it is coming.